# WireGuard: wg-quick: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf' does not exist

Tags: linux, vpn, wireguard

I am trying to setup VPN on my server with help of WireGuard. I am following this tutorial https://upcloud.com/resources/tutorials/get-started-wireguard-vpn

**After my actions I have this ERROR**

```
systemctl status wg-quick@wg0
× wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-07-17 08:31:15 UTC; 15h ago
       Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
             man:wg(8)
             https://www.wireguard.com/
             https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
   Main PID: 5700 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 5ms

Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru wg-quick[5700]: wg-quick: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf' does not exist
Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

**My actions:**

Uncommented line in file sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Applied the change below

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Configured /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 58723
PrivateKey = XXXXX


PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;ip6tables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;ip6tables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;


[Peer]
# Client Name: Unnamed
PublicKey = MY__PUB_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
```

Then I am starting WG

```
> wg-quick up wg0
wg-quick: `wg0' already exists
```

Then I am enabling WG to start automatically

```
systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0
```

**USEFULL INFORMATION**

```
ls /etc/wireguard
wg0.conf


# /lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service
[Unit]
Description=WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for %I
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
PartOf=wg-quick.target
Documentation=man:wg-quick(8)
Documentation=man:wg(8)
Documentation=https://www.wireguard.com/
Documentation=https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
Documentation=https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
Documentation=https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/wg-quick down %i
ExecReload=/bin/bash -c 'exec /usr/bin/wg syncconf %i <(exec /usr/bin/wg-quick strip %i)'
Environment=WG_ENDPOINT_RESOLUTION_RETRIES=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: is "**ERROR**" what you get after you've done "**My actions**"? or is "**My actions**" your attempt to fix the "**ERROR**" - it's not clear from your post

Comment: After my actions I have the ERROR, Updated my question

Comment: i take it you've rebooted?

Comment: Post the output of `ls /etc/wireguard` and `systemctl cat wg-quick@.service`

Comment: @Grigorios I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was facing a similar issue.. Ended up setting it with proton:
https://protonvpn.com/support/wireguard-manual-linux/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/454436)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).